# How to Redirect login to different folder

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, admin

We have 2 admin pages. one is for admin and another is for branches. We have 16 branches in our company. I have put 16 branches as different folder. One is for admin section. If I login www.xxx.com it asks login page. When admin enters it should go to admin page only. And if any branches try to login www.xxx.com, den it should redirect to their respective branches folders. Please tell me how i do dat in php/mysql.

Comment: try searching `roles` for user in web applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a new row in your mysql table called for example `login_type` and for every user you add his login type:

```
admin    - login_type = admin_folder
branch 1 - login_type = branch1_folder
```

So every time an user authenticates you redirect him to his default folder stored in `login_type`. And of course you check if he didn't landed in a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can classify the users according to admin or branch. First , you will need to store the branch for every users who can login in the site in the database. When the user login takes place, retrieve the branch from the row and redirect the his corresponding branch.